# Measuring variable with different number of Likert scale

Tags: regression, likert

I have 5 latent variable which 3 of them are measured using 5 point Likert Scale and the other 2 measured using 7 point Likert scale. is this going to be a problem when I make regression for my modmed (moderated/mediated) model?

I am planning to use SPSS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just convert both scales into one scale, so that for each value you do something like this, so you take the 5 point Likert scale and convert to a 10-point, for example, and do the same for the 7 point Likert scale:

```
FinalValue = (((OldValue - OldMininum) * (NewMaximum - NewMinimum)) / (OldMaximum - OldMinimum)) + NewMinimum
```

Comment: How are you defining "old," "new," "minimum," and so on?

Comment: Old = current value, new = new scale max, and min = new scale min...

Comment: Sorry. It's still not clear what you're recommending. Are you doing this at the level of the individual respondent? Maybe you could work through an example?